# cannot load such file -- google/apis/compute_v1, Using service accounts to create (server to server) Google Calendar events. Using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

I'm running a rails app and am trying to create google calendar events for us when a customer makes a delivery request. I've created the service account and am trying to get my [oauth working](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/auth/service-accounts) my controller is basically the same as they suggest. requiring googleauth is working because I've got the google api gem but it can't find the google/apis/compute_v1 and won't go past that. I can't find a description of where it's supposed to be coming from. Anyone know?

```
class CalendarController < ApplicationController
require 'googleauth'
require 'google/apis/compute_v1'

  def create_event
    compute = Google::Apis::ComputeV1::ComputeService.new

    # Get the environment configured authorization
    scopes =  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
    compute.authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default(scopes)
  end
end
```

Here's the errors that I get when I try and activate calendar#create_event

cannot load such file -- google/apis/compute_v1

```
Extracted source (around line #3):

    class CalendarController < ApplicationController
    require 'googleauth'
    require 'google/apis/compute_v1'

      def create_event
        compute = Google::Apis::ComputeV1::ComputeService.new

Rails.root: /Users/myname/Code/foldername/appname
```

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/calendar_controller.rb:3:in `<class:CalendarController>'
app/controllers/calendar_controller.rb:1:in`'
This error occurred while loading the following files:
   google/apis/compute_v1

Comment: Share the error message/log please.

Comment: Justs shared error stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I need to put this in my gem file gem 'google-api-client', '0.9.pre1'
I had gem 'google-api-client' and it was using an earlier version of the gem.